# Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 6 bytes

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.7

when i try to display all users for admin interface i get this error 
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 6 bytes

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

namespace AdminBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
/**
 * Description of AdminController
*
* @author saif
*/
class AdminController extends Controller {
public function valide_compteAction()
     {
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $utilisateur=$em->getRepository('WelcomeBundle:Utilisateur')->findall();      

         return $this->render('AdminBundle:admin:valide_compte.html.twig',array('i'=>$utilisateur));

}
}
```

and this is my userclass

```
namespace WelcomeBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\Type;
/**
 * Utilisateur
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="utilisateur")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Utilisateur extends BaseUser implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $nom;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $prenom;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numtelphone", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $numtelphone;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="addresse", type="string", length=40, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $addresse;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="jeton", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $jeton;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="blob", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $photo;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mailreclamation", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $mailreclamation;

 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom() {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function getPrenom() {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    public function getNumtelphone() {
        return $this->numtelphone;
    }

    public function getAddresse() {
        return $this->addresse;
    }

    public function getJeton() {
        return $this->jeton;
    }

    public function getPhoto() {
        return $this->photo;
    }

    public function getMailreclamation() {
        return $this->mailreclamation;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setNom($nom) {
        $this->nom = $nom;
    }

    public function setPrenom($prenom) {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;
    }

    public function setNumtelphone($numtelphone) {
        $this->numtelphone = $numtelphone;
    }

    public function setAddresse($addresse) {
        $this->addresse = $addresse;
    }

    public function setJeton($jeton) {
        $this->jeton = $jeton;
    }

    public function setPhoto($photo) {
        $this->photo = $photo;
    }

    public function setMailreclamation($mailreclamation) {
        $this->mailreclamation = $mailreclamation;
    }


public function json_encode()
{
    return json_encode(array(
        $this->password,
        $this->salt,
        $this->usernameCanonical,
        $this->username,
        $this->expired,
        $this->locked,
        $this->credentialsExpired,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->id,
    ));
}
}
```

how can i solve this, i have wasted a lot of time in this

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what's wrong with my post ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the serialized data in the database. Are they consistent? It is possible that the database driver assumes another data type. In this case check the blob type for the photo column. I had had a similar problem with json/array type.